# A Div has gap on sides

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my divs. Whenever I add a border to div, there is some gap inside of divs image. It has 0 margins and 0 padding. Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3VI4.jpg

There is no border gap and outline gap is added for them. Also there is no extra border, margins and padding is added inside div contents.

I have attached the live link of page in case if you didn't found a bug from my snippet. You can review the live code here: https://10xplusmedia.com/seo-services/finalproject/pageold1.html

I have tried to add border-collapse, but it didn't work. But when I add outline, gap is gone but there is no chance to add border-radius. I need border-radius anyway. So finding a solution for gap though.

There should be no gap if possible.

```css
body {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.4285;
 color: #333;
 background-color: #fff;
}
body {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 16px;
}
html {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
html {
 font-size: 10px;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
 height: 100%;
}
.pageold__1__main__div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.fgf {
 background-color: #e6e7e9;
}
.eco__eff_1 {
 overflow: hidden;
}
p {
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.stg-cs-a {
 margin: 14px 0 !important;
}
.lge p {
 margin: 15px;
 color: white;
}
.hj p {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #233346;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 1.4285;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: middle;
 -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
 touch-action: manipulation;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 background-image: none;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-primary {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #337ab7;
 border-color: #2e6da4;
}
.btn-group-sm > .btn, .btn-sm {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.form-control, .btn {
 padding: 10px 12px;
 height: auto;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn {
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn-sm {
 padding: 3px 10px;
}
.hj button {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 background-image: url("assets/images/bu.jpg");
 background-position: left center;
}
b, strong {
 font-weight: 700;
}
.stg {
 font-size: 8px;
}
.stg-cs-a .stg {
 font-size: 11px !important;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}
.stg-cs-a .stg {
 font-size: 8px !important;
 font-weight: bold;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 0px;
}
.c__dd__1 {
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.lang {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #6e7076;
 margin-left: 40px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
.langs {
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #6e7076;
 margin-left: 40px;
}
.langss {
 margin-left: 30px;
}
.mggpp__opo {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
img {
 border: 0;
}
img {
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.mggpp__opo img {
 width: 30px !important;
}
.w_100_cs__a {
 width: 100% !important;
}
.bg_img_div__o {
 background: #2F518B;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.headeR__Page__old__1 {
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageold__1__main__div">
          
          
            <div>
              <div class="bg_img_div__o">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                  <p class="headeR__Page__old__1"><b>Booking ID:</b> EC4A7305</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                  <p class="headeR__Page__old__1"><b>Booking Date:</b> Montag, 27. Jan. 2018 - Dienstag, 28. Jan. 2018</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                  <p class="headeR__Page__old__1"><b>Booking Period:</b> 2Tage</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="content__pageone_div">

            <div class=" ">
              <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-sm-3 c__dd__1">
                  <img class="w_100_cs__a" alt="" src="assets/images/gg.JPG">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 c__dd__2">
                  <p class="lang mggpp__opo"><b>  Langeoog,</b> Höhenpromenade 1, 26465 Langeoog</p>
                  <p class="langs mggpp__opo"><b> Öffnungszeiten:</b> 7:00 - 19:00 Uhr</p>
                  <p class="langss mggpp__opo">    <img style="    width: 40px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i0.JPG">
                    <img style="     width: 40px;&#10;                      margin-top: -1px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i2.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 40px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i3.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 41px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i4.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 41px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i5.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 41px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i6.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 44px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i7.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 41px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i8.JPG">
                    <img style="    width: 41px;" alt="" src="assets/images/i9.JPG">
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>


          </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

            <div class="lge fgf eco__eff_1">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6  hj">
              <p><b>Sie haben gewählt:</b><br>2x Strandkorb</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hj">
                
                  <p><b>Standort:: </b><br>Strandabschnitt: 105<br>Strandkorb: 471, 462</p>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 hj">
                  <p><b>Strandkorb: </b><br>471 / 2 Tage<br>462 / 2 Tage</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 hj">
                  <p><br>21,98 EUR<br>21,98 EUR</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" style=" background-color: #FFB506;">
              <div class="row hj">
                <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-4">
                  <p class="stg-cs-a"><b>Gesamtsumme: </b><br><span class="stg"> inkl. Steuern &amp; Gebühren <br>(inkl. 0.99 € Nutzungsentgeld pro Tag StandKorb)</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-xs-4"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-4">
                  <p><b>43,96 EUR</b></p>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button">Stornieren</button>
                  <br><br>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          </div>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images have a white edge in them. Use image editing software to crop it out.

[image]
[image]

**Edit:**
I don't see any gaps as indicated in your screenshot.
Left is Chrome 71 and right is Firefox 65 Dev Edition both on MacOS 10.14

[image]

Comment: Can you please check the mention screenshot?

Comment: I am not asking about an image gap though, of course i can see it. But can you check there is a div gap space on top and right side.

Comment: @GamersAgenda I can't replicate the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not the image try this and see if it works:

```
body, html {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Read the question carefully please!